# How to print content of file after seek

Tags: c

I am trying to print the remaining contents of a file after I do a fseek. Right now I am getting nothing returned. What's wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  FILE *fr;

  if (fr = fopen (argv[1], "r")){ 
    fseek(fr, 100, SEEK_CUR);

    char c[1];
    while (fread(c, 1, sizeof(c),fr) > 0)
        printf("%s", c);

    fclose(fr);
  }
  else{
    perror("File does not exist");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers pointed out, you are passing printf a string which may not be NULL terminated.  You are also not verifying the file being read is greater than 100 bytes. One last point, in `fread()` you swapped the `size_t size` and `size_t niters` parameters.

Here is an modified version of your program which fixes the above issues (and cleans up the spacing a bit):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fr;
    char c[1];
    struct stat sb;

    // obtains information about the file
    if (stat(argv[1], &sb) == -1)
    {
        perror("stat()");
        return(1);
    };

    // verifies the file is over 100 bytes in size
    if (sb.st_size < 101)
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "%s: file is less than 100 bytes\n", argv[1]);
       return(1);
    };

    // opens the file, or prints the error and exists
    if (!(fr = fopen (argv[1], "r")))
    {
        perror("fopen():");
        return(1);
    };

    fseek(fr, 100, SEEK_CUR);

    while (fread(c, sizeof(c), 1, fr) > 0)
        printf("%c", c[0]);

    fclose(fr);

    return(0);
}
```

You could also improve the efficiency of reading the file by changing `char c[1];` to something line `char c[1024];` and updating the while statement to:

```
    while (fread(c, sizeof(char), 1023, fr) > 0)
    {
        c[1023] = '\0';
        printf("%s", c);
    };
```

Comment: Note, reading in more than 1 byte at a time and then using printf assume that the input file is a text file without NULL characters.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot print with `%s` as your string needs to be null terminated and you only have one character.
use:

```
      printf("%c",*c);
```

not all characters are printable, check an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to see which are printable and which not. eg printing a 0 will not print anything on screen, AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a byte but trying to print it with `%s`, which expects a null-terminated string. Changing that to `%c` (and of course `c` to `*c` so that it agrees with the format string!) should fix things.

Especially if the value of the bytes you read is equal to `0`, `printf` with the `%s` specifier will output absolutely nothing (as it thinks you are repeatedly asking it to print the empty string).

Comment: extract.c:30: warning: format ‘%c’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’

Getting that error and it still prints nothing

Comment: @SuperString: It follows that you need to change `c` to `*c` so that it's in line with the format specifier. Also try printing `*c` with `%d` -- are these perhaps null bytes?

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%s",blabla)` should print a null-terminated string. for print one char use `printf("%c",c[0])`.